# android - best way to place objects / design an activity

Tags: android, android-layout

So I received a graphic interface for an application I'm building. It has some images and texts and the images are set in a specific way, and some text goes inside or on top some images.

In the android project I opened I get the default activity which is RelativeLayout, but it's hard to set all the elements exactly where they should be with the designer and editing the XML directly seems like a pain.

I also see that elements that I add always "align" to something or right/left to some other element - but what I really want to do is place them at a specific location (so the end result will be the same as the design I got). If I was building it for the web I would have used absolute positions.

What is the correct way to go about this in android?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I managed to start implementing some elements of the design in a manner that makes them look ok on the eclipse Graphical Layout and on my device.

Is this XML ok - or am I using it wrong:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgClouds"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/layout_activity_main_imgClouds"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/clouds_ltr" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBaby"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgClouds"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/layout_activity_main_imgBaby"
    android:src="@drawable/baby" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBubble"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgBaby"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bubble_ltr" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Re: "editing the XML directly seems like a pain".

Actually, that is the best way to lay out user interfaces in Android. Using XML layouts makes it very easy to get user interfaces to look exactly how you want. It's much easier to use than CSS rules for websites in my opinion. See here for more info on how to use layouts: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: but how do I place objects at a specific location?

Comment: Placing in a specific location is not a good idea, because what looks great one one device may not look good on another due to varying screen sizes, etc. @Martin Cazares' answer covers this.

Comment: @developer82, using absolute locations in Android is a mistake. You must declare all the views "related" to each other so the UI will adapt itself to all the different screen sizes and resolutions that Android allows.

Comment: @developer82 if you post a mockup of your UI (just draw some labeled boxes on a napkin and post a photo - that's good enough), perhaps we can help you construct it by using the various layouts available in Android.

Answer (score 4):

This is primarily opinion based, but there's certain things most android developers will agree, "Absolute Position" is not an option in Android, because of the OS Nature like Fragmentation in Device Screen Sizes/Densities, having an absolute position of the elements will lead to a crappy app, it will look good only in the device you are using and chances are that all the other devices will not look as you expect, you really need to look at the android design patterns and best practices to avoid a terrible GUI implementation, RelativeLayout is the best way to go, in android you must learn to love it...

Also the sooner you get used to work with XML directly in layouts will be better for you, most IDEs that help out with this functionality end up adding a lot of unnecessary code, once you go through the learning curve to build layouts using XML it totally worth it.

Hope it helps!

Regards!

Comment: thanks for the reply. please see above edit - am I on the right track or is that bad practice what I'm doing?

Comment: Regarding the XML you posted - yes, you are following bad practices. It seems that you are defaulting to trying to position the elements by using an absolute layout. This is not the correct way to do things. What you want to do is use layout_toRightOf, layout_below, and others for your xml elements inside your `RelativeLayout` to position them in relation to each other.

Comment: @BVB but once I do that - how do I position them exactly at the point they should be?

Comment: You have not provided enough information for me to answer that. Can you please show a wireframe picture of how you want to lay out your elements?

Comment: @BVB I've added the leftof and below in the above edit - doesn't this make this code ok?